# Sorting arrays in node.js -- sorted turns into unsorted

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I need to sort an array of strings in `node.js`. I'm using the `underscore` library and for the following array it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

This is the array:

```
var stringsArray = 
 ['2b9ee0e611af977edbfd6bb04a56ebe05af07bdbc2daf88e5617fb872487f27c',
  '6f009f9cb714849dba36a302d96dcd940c803bab5aa72dc25f52c26d2a32aab6',
  '980942c275b7a407650980d6be561e6260edc55316247f20c3250ffc4d3d3c2f',
  'e262181e5298faaefbfcec1f6b3e5684b50a31ed0c751f052a725a6dfafed2a7',
  'e5cc268ab1ddd6e650fb5bac1e8d2bee01d2e561674eec0198683757347ded3e'];
```

Notice that the array is already sorted. This is the sorting code, which I'd expect to do nothing here:

```
var sortedArray = underscore.sortBy(stringsArray, function (s) { return s.toLowerCase().charCodeAt() * -1; }).reverse();
```

But the resulting array is unsorted:

```
[ '2b9ee0e611af977edbfd6bb04a56ebe05af07bdbc2daf88e5617fb872487f27c',
  '6f009f9cb714849dba36a302d96dcd940c803bab5aa72dc25f52c26d2a32aab6',
  '980942c275b7a407650980d6be561e6260edc55316247f20c3250ffc4d3d3c2f',
  'e5cc268ab1ddd6e650fb5bac1e8d2bee01d2e561674eec0198683757347ded3e',
  'e262181e5298faaefbfcec1f6b3e5684b50a31ed0c751f052a725a6dfafed2a7' ]
```

This is a strange one. In most cases I checked the code works. But not this time. What's the issue? Why is the array scrambled? How do you sort it correctly?

EDIT: duh, looks like my code is only sorting on the first character. If anyone has a sort that recursively checks for the entire string I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you actually want the array to be sorted or if you want it reverse-sorted. If you want to sort the array you could just use plain javascript

```
var stringsArray = 
 ['2b9ee0e611af977edbfd6bb04a56ebe05af07bdbc2daf88e5617fb872487f27c',
  '6f009f9cb714849dba36a302d96dcd940c803bab5aa72dc25f52c26d2a32aab6',
  '980942c275b7a407650980d6be561e6260edc55316247f20c3250ffc4d3d3c2f',
  'e262181e5298faaefbfcec1f6b3e5684b50a31ed0c751f052a725a6dfafed2a7',
  'e5cc268ab1ddd6e650fb5bac1e8d2bee01d2e561674eec0198683757347ded3e'];

stringsArray.sort()
 ["2b9ee0e611af977edbfd6bb04a56ebe05af07bdbc2daf88e5617fb872487f27c",
  "6f009f9cb714849dba36a302d96dcd940c803bab5aa72dc25f52c26d2a32aab6",
  "980942c275b7a407650980d6be561e6260edc55316247f20c3250ffc4d3d3c2f",
  "e262181e5298faaefbfcec1f6b3e5684b50a31ed0c751f052a725a6dfafed2a7",
  "e5cc268ab1ddd6e650fb5bac1e8d2bee01d2e561674eec0198683757347ded3e"]
```

If you want an array sorted in reverse, you could just reverse the sorted array

```
stringsArray.sort().reverse()
 ["e5cc268ab1ddd6e650fb5bac1e8d2bee01d2e561674eec0198683757347ded3e",
  "e262181e5298faaefbfcec1f6b3e5684b50a31ed0c751f052a725a6dfafed2a7",
  "980942c275b7a407650980d6be561e6260edc55316247f20c3250ffc4d3d3c2f",
  "6f009f9cb714849dba36a302d96dcd940c803bab5aa72dc25f52c26d2a32aab6",
  "2b9ee0e611af977edbfd6bb04a56ebe05af07bdbc2daf88e5617fb872487f27c"]
```